# Is there an updated ways to import firebase/firestore app without my local sever or app being break?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently working on an application and everything is working fine until I tried to import firestore app from firebase to receive form data when submitted.I have tried to seek answers on youtube and it all seems to be the same approach as what I have tried already and it's not working. bellow is the syntax.

```
import {getFirestore, doc, setDoc, getDoc, collection, updateDoc} from "firebase/firestore";
```

And created a variable datebase by setting it to getFirestore function.

```
const db = getFirestore();
```

when the above exist within my code my app breaks and when it commented my app runs but didn't get the data to be submitted. kindly assist by providing me a way forward.

Comment: "it's not working" is really hard to help with, and "my app breaks" is lacking sufficient details on exactly what breaks. Please edit your question (there's a link right under it) to show exactly what is going wrong, and what error message you got, following the guidance in [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Doing so will drastically increase the chances that someone can help.